# data-binding options using knockouts

Tags: knockout.js

I have a menu being applied to a input box for each one that is displayed.
I applied knockouts data-binding options. The issue I am having trouble with is correctly placing it in the view model. Can someone point me where it should be placed. You will see the menu appearing but no text in the drop downs menus.
Thanks

```js
ko.observableArray.fn.pushAll = function(valuesToPush) {
    var underlyingArray = this();
    this.valueWillMutate();
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(underlyingArray, valuesToPush);
    this.valueHasMutated();
    return this;
};



function Users(user_id, password) {
    this.user_id = ko.observable();
    this.password = ko.observable();
}

var viewModel = {
    users: ko.observableArray([]),
     availableCountries: ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']),
    addUser: function() {
        this.users.push({
            user_id: "",
            password: ""
        });
    },
    addJSON: function() {
        var JSONdataFromServer = '[{"user_id":"frances","password":"password1"},{"user_id":"joe","password":"password2"}]';
        var dataFromServer = ko.utils.parseJson(JSONdataFromServer);

        // option 1
        //ko.utils.arrayPushAll(this.users(), dataFromServer);
        //this.users.valueHasMutated();
        // option 2
        //for (var i = 0, j = dataFromServer.length; i < j; i++)
        //this.users.push(dataFromServer[i]);
        //option 3
        this.users.pushAll(dataFromServer);
    }

};

viewModel.users();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'> 
    
    <form method='POST'> 
        <p>You are estimating for <span data-bind='text: users().length'>&nbsp;</span> Resource(s)</p> 
        <table data-bind='visible: users().length > 0'> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Resource</th> 
                    <th>User Levels</th>
                    <th /> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody data-bind='template: { name: "userRowTemplate", foreach: users }' /> 
        </table> 
        
        <button data-bind='click: addUser'>Add Resource</button> 
   
    </form> 
    
    <script id='userRowTemplate' type='text/html'> 
        <tr>
<td><input class='required' data-bind='value: user_id, uniqueName: true' /></td>
<td> <select data-bind="options: availableCountries"></select></td>
 
          
        </tr>
    </script> 
    
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `$parent` to your `availableCountries` in html because it is inside in `foreach` bindings, see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html).

```js
ko.observableArray.fn.pushAll = function(valuesToPush) {
    var underlyingArray = this();
    this.valueWillMutate();
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(underlyingArray, valuesToPush);
    this.valueHasMutated();
    return this;
};



function Users(user_id, password) {
    this.user_id = ko.observable();
    this.password = ko.observable();
}

var viewModel = {
    users: ko.observableArray([]),
     availableCountries: ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']),
    addUser: function() {
        this.users.push({
            user_id: "",
            password: ""
        });
    },
    addJSON: function() {
        var JSONdataFromServer = '[{"user_id":"frances","password":"password1"},{"user_id":"joe","password":"password2"}]';
        var dataFromServer = ko.utils.parseJson(JSONdataFromServer);

        // option 1
        //ko.utils.arrayPushAll(this.users(), dataFromServer);
        //this.users.valueHasMutated();
        // option 2
        //for (var i = 0, j = dataFromServer.length; i < j; i++)
        //this.users.push(dataFromServer[i]);
        //option 3
        this.users.pushAll(dataFromServer);
    }

};

viewModel.users();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'> 
    
    <form method='POST'> 
        <p>You are estimating for <span data-bind='text: users().length'>&nbsp;</span> Resource(s)</p> 
        <table data-bind='visible: users().length > 0'> 
            <thead> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Resource</th> 
                    <th>User Levels</th>
                    <th /> 
                </tr> 
            </thead> 
            <tbody data-bind='template: { name: "userRowTemplate", foreach: users }' /> 
        </table> 
        
        <button data-bind='click: addUser'>Add Resource</button> 
   
    </form> 
    
    <script id='userRowTemplate' type='text/html'> 
        <tr>
<td><input class='required' data-bind='value: user_id, uniqueName: true' /></td>
<td> <select data-bind="options: $parent.availableCountries"></select></td>
 
          
        </tr>
    </script> 
    
    
</div>
```